# Simulating user input

Tags: java, input, user-input, simulate

I want to try and simulate multiple user inputs. I have this code

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class MainThing {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        //simulating user input
        String simulatedUserInput = "apple" + System.getProperty("line.separator") +
                                    "pie" + System.getProperty("line.separator");

        InputStream savedStandardInputStream = System.in;   //to reset
        System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream(simulatedUserInput.getBytes()));
        //----

        addMsg();

        //reset
        System.setIn(savedStandardInputStream);
    }

    //function to affect
    public static void addMsg()
    {
        String msg1 = inputOutput("Enter message 1");
        String msg2 = inputOutput("Enter message 2");
        System.out.println(msg1 +" " + msg2 );
    }

    //basically a scanner
    private static String inputOutput(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String returnString = "";
        try {
            returnString = br.readLine();
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("Error reading in value");
        }
        return returnString;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to simulate "apple pie ", but when I run it the 2nd message is always null.
Is line.separator not suitable for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn´t intialize the `BufferedReader` twice. The first initialisation gets the whole input, whereas your second initialisation won´t have any further input to get, as the `Stream` did already consume all lines you previously "inserted". As though your second `readline` results in `null`

The error can be resolved this way :

```
 // Create a static BR which you only initialize once
 static BufferedReader br;

// Inside inputOutput
...
private static String inputOutput(BufferedReader br, String message) {
    ....
    if (br == null)
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    ...
}
```

Or simply initialize the `BufferedReader` beforehand and pass it to the method.

```
// function to affect
public static void addMsg() {
    BufferedReader br =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String msg1 = inputOutput(br, "Enter message 1");
    String msg2 = inputOutput(br, "Enter message 2");
    System.out.println(msg1 + " " + msg2);
}
// basically a scanner
private static String inputOutput(BufferedReader br, String message) {
    System.out.println(message);
    String returnString = "";
    try {
        returnString = br.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error reading in value");
    }
    return returnString;
}
```

Edit: 
You could also provide the `String` input as array and create a `ByteArrayInputStream` for each array element, instead of a single `ByteArrayInputStream` from a single `String`.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    //simulating user input as array
    String simulatedUserInput[] = {"apple",
                                   "pie"};

    InputStream savedStandardInputStream = System.in;   //to reset
    //----

    addMsg(simulatedUserInput);

    //reset
    System.setIn(savedStandardInputStream);
}

//function to affect
public static void addMsg(String[] simulatedUserInput)
{
    String msg = "";
    // Loop over the input array and provide the input
    for (int i = 0;i < simulatedUserInput.length; ++i) {
        System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream(simulatedUserInput[i].getBytes()));
        msg += inputOutput("Enter message " + (i + 1)) + " ";
    }
    // output the input
    System.out.println(msg);
}
```

O/P in all cases:

```
Enter message 1
Enter message 2
apple pie
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it work without editing the inputOutput function? I am not supposed to change that code.

Comment: @JarrenOng you could provide the input in two steps. As of now you do it once. After you read the first line provide the second line to the `System.in`

Comment: I split it into another line with `String simulatedUserInput2 = "pie";

System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream(simulatedUserInput2.getBytes());`

but this seems to overwrite it and return pie null

Comment: Just an extra thought, is it possible to be able to do it all in main? That is, using the System.setIn as input parameters without addMsg having parameters/arguments?

Comment: @JarrenOng you could declare and define `simulatedUserInput` as a `static class member` as of `static String simulatedUserInput[]` and instead of passing this to `addMessage` you could simply refer to the `static member` within the method. There are multiple ways to do it and to be honest for such a small programm it really doesn´t have a big affect at all. But at some point, for the sake of reality, you´d need to decide for a way that is fitting the best in terms of "good code standard"

Answer (score 1):

BufferedReader read all bytes from stream, when you pass System.in. You read only apple and forget about pie. Second time BufferedReader see that all byte from this stream have already read. This main cause why you get null.